# Correct usage of LimitExcept in Apache

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, passenger

I have a LimitExcept clause in my apache2.conf as follows

The intention was to reject PROPFIND etc before the request goes any further and fills up my application logs in Rails (using passenger)

Unfortunately I seem to have not understood the directive correctly as I am still getting messages like the following in the Rails log:

```
Message PROPFIND, accepted HTTP methods are get, head, put, post, delete, and options
```

Location    /attachment
Action
Controller
Query
Method  PROPFIND
SSL false
Agent   Microsoft-WebDAV-MiniRedir/6.1.7601

With a stacktrace as follows:

/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_controller/request.rb:32:in `_unmemoized_request_method'

/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.2.2/lib/active_support/memoizable.rb:57:in `request_method'

/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_controller/request.rb:40:in `method'

/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_controller/routing/route_set.rb:433:in `extract_request_environment'

/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_controller/routing/route_set.rb:386:in `recognize'

/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:182:in `handle_request'

/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:110:in `dispatch_unlocked'

/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:123:in `dispatch'

/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:122:in `synchronize'

/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:122:in `dispatch'

/usr
etc etc.....

Any help appreciated.

George